# how to pipe bc-calculation into shell variable

Tags: linux, shell, variables, bc

I have a calculation on a Linux shell, something like this

```
echo "scale=4;3*2.5" |bc
```

which gives me an result, now I like to pipe the result of this calculation into an Variable so that I could use it later in another command,

piping into files work, but not the piping into variables

```
echo "scale=4 ; 3*2.5" | bc > test.file
```

so in *pseudo-code* i'm looking to do  something like  this

```
set MYVAR=echo "scale=4 ; 3*2.5" | bc ; mycommand $MYVAR
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10):

You can do (in csh):

```
set MYVAR=`echo "scale 4;3*2.5" |bc`
```

or in bash:

```
MYVAR=$(echo "scale 4;3*2.5" |bc)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
MYVAR=`echo "scale=4 ; 3*2.5" | bc`
```

Note that bash doesn't like non-integer values - you won't be able to do calculations with 7.5 in bash.

Comment: Nope, can’t do that with `let`.

Comment: backticks are deprecated syntax, use `$()` instead.  http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082

Answer (score 0):

```
 MYVAR=$(echo "scale 4;3*2.5" | bc)
```